# Lisp: multi level search and replace

Tags: replace, lisp

I would like to write a `lisp` function that does multiple search and replace in a string. for example I want to replace `"a"` and `"t"` with `"e"` and `"d"` respectively in string `"bat"` resulting in bed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please post the code that you have already written.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a purely functional version:

```
(map 'string (lambda (c)
               (case c
                 (#\a #\e)
                 (#\t #\d)
                 (t c)))
     "bat")
==> "bed"
```

To make this more general purpose, you can construct the lambda at compile time with a macro:

```
(defmacro make-translation-lambda (from to)
  `(lambda (c) (case c ,@(map 'list (lambda (i o) `(,i ,o)) from to) (t c))))
(map 'string (make-translation-lambda "at" "ed") "bat")
==> "bed"
```

Note that the arguments to the macro `make-translation-lambda` must be string literals.

Alternatively, more flexibly but less efficiently, you can do

```
(defun translate-string (input from to)
  (assert (= (length from) (length to)))
  (map 'string
       (lambda (c)
         (let ((pos (position c from)))
           (if pos
               (char to pos)
               c)))
       input))
(translate-string "bed" "at" "ed")
==> "bed"
```

The performance of the version using the macro `make-translation-lambda` is linear with the string being translated (`O(length(input))`).

The performance of the function `translate-string` is `O(length(input) * length(from))`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to replace a character at a time from the original string, similar to how the [tr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_%28Unix%29) unix utility works, you should be [processing the string one character a time](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html#process) and collecting the transformed character:

```
(defun transform-chars (replacements str)
  "replacements is a list of lists: (FROM-CHAR TO-CHAR)"
  (coerce
    (loop for char across str
          for tr = (assoc char replacements)
          if (null tr) collect char
          else collect (second tr))
    'string))

(transform-chars '((#\a #\e) (#\t #\d)) "bat")
```

I'm using the `LOOP` macro with these sub-clauses:

- [for-as-across](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abae.htm)
- [for-as-equals-then](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_abad.htm)
- [collect](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_ac.htm)

Also we're [coercing the collected characters from a list into a string](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html#conv-chars).

Comment: @arbautjc, please post this type of edit as a comment, and it appears to be getting rejected

Comment: I don't understand why, but never mind... "unless" is wrong and must be replaced by "if". And "nullp" is not part of CL, it's "null". And it's coerce to 'string, not 'sequence. I don't find this kind of comment very useful, since omouse had obviously the right logic and did little coding mistakes.

Comment: Continued on meta for thos who are interested: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189407/edit-rejected-on-lisp-question

Comment: @arbautjc you got rejected because the moderators don't know the programming language, your edits are correct.

Comment: @omouse: No, code edits beyond formatting, typos, capitalization and mistaken variable names usually aren't valid and assumptions (like the one you just made about what I know or don't know in terms of programming languages) are bad. It belonged in a comment. Glad you fixed it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record:

```
(defun make-sparse-charmap (from to)
  (loop with map =
       (loop with map = (make-string 128 :initial-element #\x)
          for i from 0 below 128 do
            (setf (char map i) (code-char i))
          finally (return map))
     for x across from
     for y across to do
       (setf (char map (char-code x)) y)
     finally (return map)))

(defun tr (source from to)
  (loop with map = (make-sparse-charmap from to)
     and result = (make-string (length source) :initial-element #\x)
     for c across source
     for i from 0 do
       (setf (char result i) (char map (char-code c)))
     finally (return result)))
```

Maybe not the best idea for Unicode strings, but for ASCII will do nicely.

*EDIT*

Slightly modified it to do without extra lambdas generation.

Comment: I wanna vote you up but could you explain why you're creating a sparse-charmap? is it to handle larger amounts of replacements?

Comment: @omouse sparse charmap alludes to the name frequently used in Emacs, it's a hash-table / array / b-tree kind of structure for storing function references to the keys being typed. It is sparse in the sense that it has a default, which just returns whatever you give it, and everything you add is an "extra" functionality. In Emacs, however, it wouldn't be an array. But for smaller sets of letters an array would be a very efficient solution.